# Clearing USART (UART) interrupt flags in an STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, interrupts, stm32f1

I am using an STM32F105 to communicate with a Linx GPS chip using a UART.

If I don't use interrupts (if I just poll the RX flag) then it works just fine.  But I'm getting unexpected results when trying to use interrupts.

For example, if I only enable the RXNE ("RX not empty") interrupt using `USART_ITConfig(USARTx, USART_IT_RXNE)`, then the code should only vector to the ISR for this one specific event.  But the interrupt is being triggered for an Overrun condition, too.

As far as clearing the flags, it seems that the method depends on the flag. 
To clear the Overrun flag (`USART_IT_ORE`), the User Manual explains that I should first read the `USARTx_SR` register, then read the `USARTx_DR` register.  This does work; the flag is cleared.

There is also a `USART_ClearITPendingBit()` function, but it only accepts a small subset of flags.

There are eight different interrupt sources that can be selectively enabled, and ten different flags.  *Is there a summary somewhere of how to manage all of these flags?*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally, you only need to handle the interrupt flags which you have specifically enabled with `USART_ITConfig()`.

However, if you enable the RXNE interrupt (`USART_ITConfig(USARTx, USART_IT_RXNE)`) then this *also* enables the Overrun interrupt!  So you must handle both of those.

[image: intmap]

The USART flags can be confusing.  There are separate status flags and interrupt flags and they share similar names.  For example: `USART_IT_RXNE` and `USART_FLAG_RXNE`.

In addition, there are various methods to clear these flags.  For example, the `USART_ClearITPendingBit()` function only works for four (of the ten) possible flags.

Here is a summary of the interrupt flags and how to use them. These are specific for the STM32F105, but are representative:

---

**USART_IT_TXE** - "Transmit Data register empty"

- It is cleared automatically when calling `USART_SendData()`

---

**USART_IT_RXNE** - "Receive Data register not empty"

- It is cleared automatically when calling `USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)`
- It can be cleared manually by calling `USART_ClearITPendingBit(USARTx, USART_IT_RXNE)`

---

**USART_IT_TC** - "Transmission complete"

- It is cleared automatically by:

  - `USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_TC)` followed by
  - `USART_SendData()`
- It can be also be cleared manually by calling `USART_ClearITPendingBit(USARTx, USART_IT_TC)`

---

**USART_IT_CTS** - "CTS change"

- Cleared by calling `USART_ClearITPendingBit(USARTx, USART_IT_CTS)`

---

**USART_IT_LBD** - "LIN Break detected"

- Cleared by calling `USART_ClearITPendingBit(USARTx, USART_IT_LBD)`

---

**USART_IT_PE** - "Parity error"

- Cleared by:

  - `USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_PE)` followed by
  - `USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)`

---

**USART_IT_NE** - "Noise error"

- Cleared by:

  - `USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_NE)` followed by
  - `USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)`

---

**USART_IT_ORE** - "Overrun error"

- Cleared by:

  - `USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_ORE)` followed by
  - `USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)()`

---

**USART_IT_IDLE** - "Idle line detected"

- Cleared by:

  - `USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_IDLE)` followed by
  - `USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)()`

Comment: Yep, I answered my own question :)  If I had found a list like this earlier, it would have saved me a good amount of time. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: This answer is gold; very clear reference of how to clear each of these interrupts.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add some my experience on this problem, 
I follow the instructions:

USART_IT_ORE - "Overrun error"

Cleared by:
USART_GetITStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_ORE) followed by
USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)()

Is seems not work, and the following command work for me instead:

USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_IT_ORE) followed by
USART_ReceiveData(USARTx)

If you look into the functions:

USART_GetFlagStatus() and
USART_ReceiveData()

You will find what exactly Bitsmack wrote before...
"First read the USARTx_SR register, then read the USARTx_DR register."

Hopefully it work for you and save lot more time on this issue.=)

Comment: Thanks for your information! I don't recognize USART_GetFlat(). Can you tell me where it comes from?

Comment: I am sorry that I wrongly typed on the command,, it should be USART_GetFlagStatus() followed by USART_ReceiveData(), the original post was corrected. Thanks Bitsmack.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It looks like the function names have changed. Are you using a Standard Peripheral Library or one of the STMCube HALs? For which family of microcontrollers?

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. BUT: I receive one character on STM32L476, no further bytes are received (no signal on oszi), but permanent receive a FE (framing error) interrupt. Cannot even clear this interrupt. Any ideas what's the reason?

Comment: @peets - There is a way to clear the Framing Error (FE) flag.  You need to call
  `LL_USART_ClearFlag_ORE(USARTx_INSTANCE); ` which writes to the ICR register `WRITE_REG(USARTx->ICR, USART_ICR_ORECF);`.  That should clear the Framing Error (FE) flag.  Also, if you have Error Interrupt Enable (EIE) set, you may enter error handling code which sits forever.  If you're getting framing errors check baud rate and line breaks (UART line staying low for period of time).

Answer (score 1):

reading `status` and `data` registers clears overrun error.

````cpp
uint32_t cnt_rx2_overrun;
void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  uint32_t status = USART2->SR;
  uint8_t ch;
  if (status & USART_SR_RXNE) { // rx data
    ch = USART2->DR;
    // parse data
  }
  else if (status & USART_SR_ORE){ // overrun error
    ch = USART2->DR; // reading clears the ORE flag
    cnt_rx2_overrun++;
  }

}
```
````